# Loading Flexigrid for jQuery with JSON String

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to load the Flexigrid by using a JSON String which is returned by a WCF Service.

My Service has a `public string GetContacts(string CustomerID)` method and it returns a Json string.

That JSON string is created from a List object by using 
`System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` class. So, my aim is to bind the JSON string to the my Flexigrid as objects. I convert the web service result to objects using

```
var customer = eval("("+result+")");
```

The result is the JSON string being returned from service.  Is there any way to bind customer objects to Flexigrid?

Answer (score 20):

Flexigrid requires a format as follows in json

**EDIT** Thanks to EAMann for the format update.

```
 total: (no of rec)
 page : (page no)
 rows : [{cell: [ (col1 value) , (col2 value) ,.. ] },
        {cell: [ (col1 value) , (col2 value) ,.. ] }]
```

in order to bind the data to the grid i prefer sending the data across the wire and then formatting it on the client, but thats just me heres an example

```
function formatCustomerResults(Customers) {
  var rows = Array();

  for (i = 0; i < Customers.length; i++) {
    var item = Customers[i];
    //Do something here with the link
    var link = "alert('opening item " + item.DealGuid + "');"

    rows.push({
      cell: [item.DealId,
        item.Created,
        item.CurrentStatus,
        item.LastNote,
        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="' + link + '" >view</a>'
      ]
    });
  }

  return {
    total: Customers.length,
    page: 1,
    rows: rows
  };
}
```

and then all you need is

```
$("#FlexTable").flexAddData(formatCustomerResults(eval(data)));
```

ps this last bit is jquery syntax

Comment: Pls help me to change the url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064493/changing-jquery-flexgrids-data

Answer (score 3):

almog.ori's answer is almost perfect.  In fact, that's just about how I had built things before trying to Google the solution.  One exception, though.

The JSON object should be:

```
total: (no of rec),
page : (page no),
rows : [{cell: [ (col1 value) , (col2 value) ,.. ] },
        {cell: [ (col1 value) , (col2 value) ,.. ] }]
```

If you neglect the array format of the `rows` element, you'll end up choking Flexigrid and throwing all sorts of errors.  But I've verified that this works *flawlessly* as long as you remember which parts of the script take JSON objects and which parts take arrays of JSON objects.

Answer (score 3):

This is an older post but I thought I would add another way to use the excellent script provided by almog.ori.

The OP said that his data was being returned from a WCF service.  If you mark the operation contract body style as bare you can use the preProcess property to add your formatCustomerResults (or other function) function to initially load the grid.

Like this:

```
$("#gridContainer").flexigrid({
url: '/YourService.svc/..',
method: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
preProcess: formatCustomerResults,
...
});
function formatCustomerResults(data){
...
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the dataType option set to json.

```
$('#gridContainer').flexigrid({
  singleSelect: true,
  showToggleBtn: false,
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure also that you are using the correct HTTP method, default is POST

To use GET:

```
 $("#gridContainer").flexigrid({
    url: '/json/files.json',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
```

...

Answer (score 1):

preProcess solution by **nameEqualsPNamePrubeGoldberg** works perfect.

This is how my custom function for preProcess looks like.

```
var rows = Array();
$.each(data.rows,function(i,row){
    rows.push({id:row.val1, cell:[row.val2,row.val3]});
});

return {
      total:data.total,
      page:data.page,
      rows:rows
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to follow this sample to parse your JSON code and make requests to server:

Step 1: Parse using a function

```
function parsedForm(json)
{
var h = "";

if (json.post.val1)
    h += "<b>Value 1</b>: " + json.post.val1 + "<br />";

h += "<b>Value 2</b>: " + json.post.val2 + "<br />";
h += "<b>Value 3</b>: " + json.post.val3 + "<br />";

if (json.post.val4)
    h += "<b>Value 4</b>: " + json.post.val4 + "<br />";

$('#fdata').empty().html(h);
$('.formdata').slideDown();

return json;
}
```

Step 2: The flexigrid view code

```
$("#flex1").flexigrid({
    url: 'post2.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    colModel : [
        {display: 'ISO', name : 'iso', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
        {display: 'Name', name : 'name', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
        {display: 'Printable Name', name : 'printable_name', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
        {display: 'ISO3', name : 'iso3', width : 130, sortable : true, align: 'left', hide: true},
        {display: 'Number Code', name : 'numcode', width : 80, sortable : true, align: 'right'}
        ],
    searchitems : [
        {display: 'ISO', name : 'iso'},
        {display: 'Name', name : 'name', isdefault: true}
        ],
    sortname: "iso",
    sortorder: "asc",
    usepager: true,
    title: 'Countries',
    useRp: true,
    rp: 15,
    showTableToggleBtn: true,
    width: 700,
    onSubmit: addFormData,
    preProcess: parsedForm,
    height: 200
});
```

Step 3: Additonally, you can validate or serialize the data to request server

```
function addFormData(){
    //passing a form object to serializeArray will get the valid data from all the objects, but, if the you pass a non-form object, you have to specify the input elements that the data will come from
    var dt = $('#sform').serializeArray();
    $("#flex1").flexOptions({params: dt});
    return true;
}


$('#sform').submit(function (){
    $('#flex1').flexOptions({newp: 1}).flexReload();
    return false;
});
```

I hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make total your first element in you JSON string like this.

```
`{"total" : 2,"page":1,"rows":[ {"cell" : ["226 CLAVEN LN", "312"]},{"cell" : ["1377 FAIRFAX PIKE","280"]}]}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the latest flex code broke the solution using preProcess.

```
       addData: function (data) { //parse data

            if (p.dataType == 'json') {
                data = $.extend({rows: [], page: 0, total: 0}, data);
            }
            if (p.preProcess) {
                data = p.preProcess(data);
            }
```

You need to flip it so that the preProcess if comes before the type JSON if.  Otherwise the function listed as an answer does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's old, I know... But here is an example of json that works:

```
{
    "total": 5,
    "page": "1",
    "rows": [
        {"cell": [1, "asd", "dsa", "2013-07-30"]},
        {"cell": [2, "asd", "dsa", "2013-07-30"]},
        {"cell": [3, "asd", "dsa", "2013-07-30"]},
        {"cell": [4, "asd", "dsa", "2013-07-30"]},
        {"cell": [5, "asd", "dsa", "2013-07-30"]}
    ]
}
```

(5 results in total; first page (they are NOT zero-based); 5 lines of data, each containing { ID, "asd", "dsa", "a date" } )