# Populate Flexigrid with an array or populate it by code

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I use this code to populate a flexigrid but it does not work

```
$("#GrdRoom").flexAddData(['1','2','3']);
$("#GrdRoom").flexReload();
```

In this code I want to add a row to grid with values 1, 2, 3.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexigrid accepts special Jsnon format:

```
total: (no of rec),
page : (page no),
rows : [{cell: [ (col1 value) , (col2 value) ,.. ] },
        {cell: [ (col1 value) , (col2 value) ,.. ] }]
```

For Example:

```
    {
    "page": "1",
    "total": "9",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cell": [
                "1",
                "text1",
                "user1",
                "date1"
            ]
        }
     ]
   }
```

Comment: thanks, but how i can use the flexAddData method ? :( i need to this method to add to my flexigrid

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469852/loading-flexigrid-for-jquery-with-json-string

Answer (score -1):

For those who just want to painlessly add one (or more) rows, without messing with JSONs, reloading data, and Flexigrid's functions.

Dirty, but working:

```
$("#yourFlexigridTable tbody").append(
"<tr>\
    <td><div style='text-align: center;'>A</div></td>\
    <td><div>B</div></td>\
    <td><div style='text-align: right;'>C</div></td>\
    <td><div style='text-align: center;'>D</div></td>\
</tr>");
```

`<div>` tags in `<td>` tags are mandatory for proper formatting. Use `style` attribute to format cells according to your table's style.

Comment: This is not correct! You cand append a part of html to tbody of flexigrid this way.