# how to fill flexi grid using json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, flexigrid

i am new to flexi grid and want to bind a data

**Code**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".fgrid").flexigrid({
            url: '../_AJAX/ajaxCall-InterestSubsidy.aspx',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'MODE': 'BindFlexiGrid' },
            colModel: [
                       { display: 'Id', name: 'DistrictId', width: 20, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                       { display: 'Name', name: 'DistrictName', width: 20, sortable: true, align: 'left' }
                      ],
            sortname: "Name",
            sortorder: "asc",
            usepager: true,
            title: 'List of District',
            useRp: true,
            rp: 10,
            showTableToggleBtn: true,
            width: 805,
            height: 200

        });


    });
```

**Server side code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["MODE"] != null)
    {
        if (Request.Form["MODE"] == "BindGrid")
        {
            SelectState();
        }
        else if (Request.Form["MODE"] == "BindFlexiGrid")
        {
            SelectState2();
        }
    }


}



public void SelectState2()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        pList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        dt = sa.GetDataTableWithSP("SPSelectDistrictWithSelect", pList);

        Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

i have set a 'data' attribute in flexi grid, i don't know it is valid or not but i want pass something to 'ajaxCall-InterestSubsidy.aspx' so proper method can be called.

1) How to pass something(such as Request.Form["MODE"]) to server side code ?

2) And what is the proper way to bind this flexi grid ?

3) using above code i am not able to fill this grid

4) can any one give me a proper documentation for flexi grid

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source code for [post-json.php](https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/blob/master/demo/post-json.php). It's quite possible to strip that example down quite a bit.

Basic things to remember:

1. The variables at the top of your ajax php page are required. You will use them in your query and Flexigrid posts them to your ajax page by default.
2. Then, process your query into a json response and echo it out on that page. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209926/populate-flexigrid-with-an-array-or-populate-it-by-code) about how the json should be structured.
3. Your ajax page will be the link you will use for your ajax url in the Flexigrid parameters that you set within the $(document).ready() of your calling page.